# Definite and indefinite article use in this sentence and change in meaning

Tags: articles

> This is a real war, and the whole of the city is on edge.

How the meaning of this sentence changes if ALL the articles are removed, like so:

> This is real war, and whole of city is on edge.

Comment: In practice it doesn't make any real difference to the meaning whether you include an article or not in ***a real war***. Come to that, t doesn't make any *real* difference whether you include the word ***real*** either. But "whole of city" isn't valid English, so I think this question nets down to Off Topic proofreading anyway.

Comment: I'd say 'a real war' here is the preferred choice. 'It must be classified as a war rather than say a mere border skirmish'. 'This is real war' would be used to mean 'really fierce engagements rather than say a longish lull in a declared war'. // As FF says, 'the whole of city is on edge' is unacceptable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use of both a zero article and definite article.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/257323/use-of-both-a-zero-article-and-definite-article) Also [Why isn't there an article before "conflict"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/273233/) and [No indefinite article before the word 'battle'](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/151632/), among others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove the articles the sentence ceases to be English.

A native speaker would probably be able to understand the gist, but mentally inserting the articles in places that are reasonable.

It is possible to omit the article before "real war" because it is possible to use "war" as a non-count noun.  There is little change in meaning.

It is not possible to omit the articles before "city" in English.

Comment: Thanks. How about the omissions of articles in headlines and headings, like in this one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_of_London

Comment: How about it? That's a title, and a proper noun. It's not a grammatical sentence.  It is like saying "Dog"... it's a word, but it isn't a sentence.  There's no grammar.  If you are putting words together to make a sentence, then you need sentence grammar. Sometimes that means you have to have some articles.   Look at the rest of the Wikipedia page and you'll see sentences, and the word "the" is used very often.

Comment: This title looks like a proper sentence. Still no ‘the’ before city: https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2022-01-24/city-of-london-s-10-trillion-chinese-conduit-plans-for-growth

Comment: Not a sentence.